# Adding an attibute and value to an xml using xml.dom.minidom python

Tags: python, xml, minidom

How can I add an attribut and value to an XML document using `xml.dom.minidom` in Python.

My XML is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PackageInfo xmlns="http://someurlpackage">


<data ID="http://someurldata1">data1</data >
<data ID="http://someurldata2">data2</data >
<data ID="http://someurldata3">data3</data >
</PackageInfo>
```

I want to add a new 'data' tag and it's id as 'http://someurldata4' and value as data4. So that the resulting xml will be as below. Sorry I don't want to use xml.etree.ElementTree

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PackageInfo xmlns="http://someurlpackage">
<data ID="http://someurldata1">data1</data >
<data ID="http://someurldata2">data2</data >
<data ID="http://someurldata3">data3</data >
<data ID="http://someurldata4">data4</data >
</PackageInfo>
```

Comment: Sure, I won't stop you if you want to go through the pain, but why do you not want to use ElementTree, as a matter of interest?

Comment: i don't want to use elementtree because the xml header tag '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' is not present in the output.

Comment: @user1654136: Use ElementTree 1.3: http://effbot.org/zone/elementtree-13-intro.htm

Comment: @njzk2: Because the prolog is only included if the output is not ASCII or UTF-8; it is redundant otherwise. ElementTree (python2.7 and up) lets you force the inclusion but the OP is on an older Python version. See [XML header getting removed after processing with elementtree](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12457400)

Comment: funny, i thought there would always be a prolog in an xml file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create new DOM elements with the [`Document.createElement()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.Document.createElement), new DOM attributes can be added with the [`Element.setAttribute()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.Element.setAttribute):

```
newdata = doc.createElement(u'data')
newdata.setAttribute(u'ID', u'http://someurldata4')
```

You then have to create a text node and add that as a child to the `newdata` Element, using the [`Document.createTextNode()`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.Document.createTextNode) and [`Node.appendChild()`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.Node.appendChild) methods:

```
newdata.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(u'data4'))
```

Now you can add the new element to your document root:

```
doc.documentElement.appendChild(newdata)
```

In other words, use the [Python implementation of the DOM API](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.Node.appendChild).