# XDocument: Create custom declaration

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

I want to create Windows Media Player playlist files with XDocument. Therefore I have to create this declaration:

```
<?wpl version="1.0"?>
```

However, the `XDeclaration` object doesn't allow to replace "xml" with "wpl". Is there a proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a processing instruction, not an XML declaration.

```cs
new XProcessingInstruction("wpl", "version=\"1.0\"")
```

Your document is still an XML document, so you can additionally include `<?xml version="1.0"?>` at the top, but that's optional.

Comment: How do I add this object to the XDocument?

Comment: I think my code sample should give you enough to go on. Adding a processing instruction works like adding any other type of node. You'll figure it out.

Comment: But the wpl file format as generated by Windows Media Player only has the <wpl /> instruction. Can this be done somehow?

Comment: As I was trying to say. The XML declaration is optional. You can have it or omit it, that won't change very much. The XML declaration is for configuring *the XML parser*, it sets the version (1.0 or 1.1) and encoding of the file. A processing instruction is for configuring *the application* that sits behind the parser. You can have both and nothing will break. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4679212/18771